# Text cannot be read using pyTesseract

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to extract logo from the PDFs.

I am applying GaussianBlur, finding the contours  and extracting only image. But Tesseract cannot read the text from that Image?

[image: This is the extracted image]

Answer (score 0):

Removing the frame around the letters often helps tesseract recognize texts better. So, if you try your script with the following image, you'll have a better chance of reading the logo.

[image]

With that said, you might ask how you could achieve this for this logo and other logos in a similar fashion. I could think of a few ways off the top of my head but I think the most generic solution is likely to be a pipeline where text detection algorithms and OCR are combined.

1. Thus, you might want to check out this repository that provides [a text detection algorithm based on R-CNN](https://github.com/eragonruan/text-detection-ctpn).
2. You can also step up your tesseract game by applying a few different image pre-processing techniques. I've recently written a pretty simple guide to Tesseract and some image pre-processing techniques. In case you'd like to check them out, here I'm sharing the links with you:

   - [Getting started with Tesseract - Part I: Introduction](https://medium.com/@bkaankuguoglu/getting-started-with-tesseract-part-i-2a6a6b1cf75e)
   - [Getting started with Tesseract - Part II: Image Pre-processing](https://medium.com/@bkaankuguoglu/getting-started-with-tesseract-part-ii-f7f9a0899b3f)
3. However, you're also interested in this particular logo, or font, you can also try training tesseract with this font by following the instructions given [here](http://3.%20However,%20you're%20also%20interested%20in%20this%20particular%20logo,%20or%20font,%20you%20can%20also%20try%20training%20tesseract%20with%20this%20font%20by%20following%20the%20instructions%20given%20here.).

Comment: Is it working for you with that image?.It is not working for me.In case,it's working for you, then please share the code.Thanks,for the links.I loved it.

Comment: I have done a similar work using the links above but I'm not allowed to share it. Tesseract is not designed to read text from logos, in fact, it can only read texts that are clearly visible. You should find a way to extract that text from the image somehow. My suggestion is to use a code that already does that, go play with that. Even then, you might have a problem since the characters there are tilted and too close. Before getting into other image manipulations, I've tried different thresholding filters and the one that I combined Gaussian Blur and Adaptive Thresholding was able to read it.